# Where's the search box?

Tags: support

The help center says there's a search box in the upper right corner of every page. I don't see one anywhere. Where is it?

Comment: It’s at the top in the middle. Scroll to the top and there it is. If it’s not there, disable your extensions and scripts and try again.

Comment: It used to be in the top right corner, afair, but recently the whole SE network underwent a topbar redesign, and the search box is now closer to the centre, a bit to the left. I think the help centre should be updated, but who cares :p

Comment: On mobile the search button disappears when you click into a question.

Comment: I've just updated [my canonical answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9332/31394) on the search facility.

Comment: I've reported this on meta.se: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308958/reference-to-the-search-bar-location-needs-to-be-updated

Comment: @doppel DUPE! :-P