# Official Unofficial Blog Support Post

Tags: discussion, blog

(I hope it's OK to do this here, since we don't have any better place to do it at the moment. I am looking into other options for support, so this post will hopefully be just an interim solution).

Now that the SF&F blog is off-site, any support or troubleshooting has to go through the blog owner and maintainers, and not the mods or Stack Exchange. So, the SE "contact us" link is no longer of any use.

To try and keep these conversations out of chat, comments, other posts etc. I'd like to start a support thread here for people having issues. If you see a problem with the blog, or have troubles posting, logging in, etc. post here, and we'll get back to you.

If your question involves personal/private information, just post a note here, and someone will contact you at the email you used to sign up to the blog.

Comment: #1issue, I wish that Jack guy would write more articles.

Comment: If this post turns out to be more than just an interim solution, let me know if you'd like the [meta-tag:faq] tag added to it.

Answer (score 6):

I'm writing this answer here so that you can easily ping me directly about any major **technical issues**. If the site is suddenly loading very slowly, not at all, spitting up some errors, or there are any functionality problems, then please ping me.

Really, you can contact myself, [Jack B. Nimble](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1148/jack-b-nimble) or [KutuluMike](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2816/kutulumike) about any of the issues, and we'll pretty quickly route them to whichever of us is best-suited to fix it. But most things related to the hosting or blog installation will end falling in my lap. I'm happy to foist off everything else that I can to the others!

---

There will likely be a support form and report issues email in the near future, once I can be reasonably sure I won't be receiving spam email notifications every 10 minutes. I'll update this answer once those features are live, but will still be happy to respond to pings here.

Comment: If I visit http://thesffblog.com/wp-login.php while logged out, Firefox and Chrome complain about the lack of HTTPS.  This isn't necessarily a high-priority issue, but you might want to set up Let's Encrypt or something similar.  Changing the URL to use HTTPS causes a certificate mismatch error.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks for the heads-up. I didn't think about that, because Chrome never warned me. My bad! I'm getting SSL set up now. It may take a couple days because of the billing and verification and customer service and then my part (actually, my part should mostly be done outside of the quick plug ins, now, just gotta wait on the host...)

Comment: @Kevin Host support went much more quickly than expected (guess they really do run 24/7 support). The blog is now running on SSL and you shouldn't get any content mismatch errors, either. HTTPS is the default.